How to read the next chunk of an Arrow.Stream while processing the current one?
Currently, I am processing an Arrow.Table by chunks as follows:
input_stream = Arrow.Stream("/path/to/table.arrow")
for chunk in input_stream
    process_chunk(Tables.rowtable(chunk))
end

Doing so, I've noticed that the bottle neck is in reading the next chunk from the Arrow.Stream. It takes twice the amount of time to read a chunk than to process it. So, I wonder if I could be reading the next chunk while processing the current chunk. How could I achieve this in Julia? In Python, I would probably use multithreading and a Queue as a buffer; with one process I would read the next chunks and add them to the Queue while with another process I would consume and process the chunks from the Queue.

Like in Python, you can also spawn threads in Julia. AFAIK there is no GIL limiting the performance as opposed to Python. Locks can be used to protect a queue shared by multiple threads. Note that I am not an expert of Julia.

Your Queue could probably be a Channel in Julia:

A Channel is a waitable first-in first-out queue which can have multiple tasks reading from and writing to it.


Spawning threads for I/O is not the best use for threads. Try increasing the chunk size until process_chunk has a significant compute cost.
That alone might be good enough, but if you want to parallelize: run one process_chunk in a thread while you read the next chunk in the main thread. This way you only buffer two big chunks that can be as high as your max memory usage target and only stop doing I/O when you have the 2 chunks using all the memory you have.
I'm assuming you want and have to process the chunks in order.
